# Generate class variable getter setter based on constructor parameters eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the below Java constructed generated by eclipse.

```
public CustomAudienceAdapter(AdAccount adAccount, String string, String string2, EnumSubtype valueWebsite,
            String audienceRule) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
```

**What I am trying to do**?

- Generate private class variable from these constructor arguments
- Generate getter setter of these variables
- Assign constructor variables to class variable (`this.var = var`)

I found many articles on generating constructor from class variables but din't found reverse.

Is there any **way** we can achieve above using **shortcut** or eclipse UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with eclipse, move mouse to 1 of the parameters variable name, then press ctrl+1. then comes a little popup, where you can select "assign all parameters to new fields". press it. this solves tasks 1 and 3. for the getter and setter, go towards the newly generated member variables and again move the mouse to the variable name and press ctrl+1 again and select generate getter and setter. other way for getter and setter is alt+shift+s -->generate getter and setter and select all